# Insert slash at specific place in string with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to write a function that will insert a backlash into the broken URL that for some reason is missing a second backslash after http, and I only want to return fixed version, for example

```
 addSlash(http:/example.net) ->  http://example.net
 addSlash(https:/example.net`) -> https://example.net
```

I thought this could be solved with preg_replace in one line of code, but  I can't get it to work. Using $url = 'http:/example.net' and

```
preg_replace("@^(https?:)(.*?)@", "\1/\2", $url);
```

I'm getting back `/ /example.net` , as if 'http' is not matched and placed into `\1`.

Any suggestions ? I would like to avoid callbacks and anonymous function if possible, cause this is supposed to run on an older version of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^(https:|http:)?[\\/](?![\\/])(.*)/
```

Something like that should [work](https://regex101.com/r/jL6sU4/1) for you.

```
$re = "/^(https:|http:)?[\\/](?![\\/])(.*)/mi"; 
$str = "https:/regex101.com\nhttp:/regex101.com\nhttps://regex101.com"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '$1//$2' , $str);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: have you tested it with php ? I just run the code and i got pretty much the same result as before

Comment: Sorry, updated the code, just tested, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
preg_replace('@^(https*:)(/.*)@', '\1/\2', $url);
```

Or even:

```
preg_replace('@^(https*:)@', '\1/', $url);
```